# Always show selected item in TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there a way to have the selected item of a `TreeView` always shown? In other words, to disallow collapsing of the nodes that contain the selected item?

I have a `TreeView` with a hierarchical data template

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Properties, Mode=OneWay}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ExpanderTreeViewItemStyle.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ComplexProperty}" ItemsSource="{Binding Properties, Mode=OneWay}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:SimpleProperty}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

styled so that only the nodes without children are focusable (the container items are templated to use an expander instead of the usual tree with +/- buttons, but that shouldn't make a difference).

When a leaf node is selected, how do I prevent the containing node(s) from being wrapped, hiding the selected node?

Here's the style for reference

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Grid Margin="8,4">
                    <Border Name="ItemBorder" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="0.3" Padding="6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Grid>
                            <Expander Name="StructuredItemExpander">
                                <Expander.Header>
                                    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"/>
                                </Expander.Header>
                                <ItemsPresenter/>
                            </Expander>

                            <ContentPresenter Name="AtomicItemContents" ContentSource="Header" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="TreeViewItem.HasItems" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="StructuredItemExpander" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="AtomicItemContents" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="ItemBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="True"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="ItemBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Aqua"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>

    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: You can try to manage `IsSelected` property inside a treeview items and disallow collapsing using a `DataTrigger` Btw, can you share the item style?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I've added the item style for reference. Can you elaborate how a DataTrigger could help?